# TinyMCE stops working after parent element is removed from and re-inserted into the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE instance running inside a div, which is in a list of sortable div elements. After the container div get's removed and re-inserted back in to the dom, TinyMCE is still showing but stops working. I'm not entirely sure what is happening there, but is there a way to reactivate this? I'm using TinyMCE 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think after removed the div, the attached handlers of div also removed.
When you reinserted this back into the dom, this time the relative handlers are not attached with this div, perhahps TinyMCE is not working so. I think you need to re-assign the relative handlers with this div when you reinserted into dom.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Are you recreating the dom you have reinsered, Or you just stored the reference of that dom before delete it?

Comment: I'm using the jquery sortable plugin, so I'm pretty sure it's keeping the reference and re-inserting at the new location.